# How to select the appropriate record/records from a group of records when using either MAX or MIN aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

How to select the appropriate record/records from a group of records when using either MAX or MIN aggregate functions so that the record/records match the value returned by the aggregate function?

I need to use the NorthWind.products database table ( http://www.zentut.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2013/06/Northwind-Sample-Database-Diagram.pdf ) in order to find the most expensive product in each category. So far I have tried two variants:

```
SELECT CategoryID, ProductID, ProductName, MAX(UnitPrice) MostExpensive
FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Products] as A
GROUP BY CategoryID;
```

This code produces the error "Column 'NORTHWND.dbo.Products.ProductID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."   I have perfectly understood the reason. It's OK.

The second variant was:

```
SELECT CategoryID, ProductID, ProductName
FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Products] as A
WHERE UnitPrice = (
                    SELECT MAX(UnitPrice) FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Products] AS B GROUP BY CategoryID HAVING A.CategoryID = B.CategoryID
                    )
```

This one works fine, the records returned are the right ones, but I would like to have 4 columns in the first SELECT, the fourth should be the maximum price in each category. Can I change the SQL query to achieve that or should I tried a third variant?

Answer (score 3):

For `SQL Server >= 2005`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CategoryID,
           ProductID,
           ProductName,
           UnitPrice,
           RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC)
    FROM dbo.Products
) t
WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```

For `SQL Server < 2005`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        p.CategoryID,
        p.ProductID,
        p.ProductName,
        p.UnitPrice
FROM dbo.Products p
JOIN (
    SELECT CategoryID, UnitPrice = MAX(UnitPrice)
    FROM dbo.Products
    GROUP BY CategoryID
) t ON t.UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice AND t.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
```